# How to round BigDecimal money calculations in Java to 2 decimal places using the best RoundingMode?

Tags: java, bigdecimal, quantitative-finance

Suppose I have a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) `amount` and another [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) `tax`.

I want to perform the following calculation :

```
amountWithoutTax = amount - tax
```

`amount` and `tax` are *supposed* to be in the format `YYYY.XX` (i.e. precision of 2).  So that means `amountWithoutTax` should also inherit a precision of 2.

However, in the *unlikely* case `amount` or `tax` have 3 or higher precision, `amountWithoutTax` would also inherit 3 or higher precision.

What is the appropriate way to handle this situation from a rounding perspective? When it comes to money, $45.134 doesn't make sense as there are no coins with lower value than a cent.

Here are the options I have (I think) using the RoundingMode class :

1. [CEILING](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#CEILING)
2. [DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#DOWN)
3. [FLOOR](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#FLOOR)
4. [HALF_DOWN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_DOWN)
5. [HALF_EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN)
6. [HALF_UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_UP)
7. [UP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#UP)

At the moment we are using CEILING, so it just rounds up.  But , to be honest, I am just randomly guessing here.  How do I know what is the official / correct way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe it would be a business decision.

Comment: Wait until you learn about *millage rates*.

Comment: "When it comes to money, $45.134 doesn't make sense as there are no coins with lower value than a cent." That may be true for a grocery store but any financial business will disagree.

Comment: Normally in finance you would use one of the HALF_EVEN or "banker's rounding".

Comment: _What is the appropriate way to handle this situation from a rounding perspective?_ The appropriate way is to ditch BigDecimal which has all sorts of downsides (such as: 0 does not equal 0 - not if they have different decimal precision counts). Use `long`, to represent atomic units. Which are cents for euros and dollars, yen for yen, satoshi for bitcoin, and so forth - every currency has an atomic unit. Every place you end up with sub-atomics (which happens all the time), you write explicit code to do the right thing (generally, round in bank's favour, sometimes, distribute at random).

Comment: You have to use the right operation to compare BigDecimals: https://www.baeldung.com/java-bigdecimal-zero

Comment: In China, mostly we agree the half up rounding mode.

Comment: Usually, it’s best not to round the values at all, so you don’t introduce rounding errors.  When *presenting* the values in a user interface, you use a NumberFormat that rounds the value.  [NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()) will in fact do exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here are the options I have (I think) using the RoundingMode class :
> …
> How do I know what is the official / correct way to handle this?

Ask your team, ask the stakeholder with financial decision-making authority. Different companies & departments have different policies with regard to rounding, truncating, and allocating extra penny.

Tip: [HALF-EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN) is known as [*bankers’ rounding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_half_to_even) for a reason. But, really, the choice of rounding mode is *not* the programmer’s call, it is the accountant’s call.

> $45.134 doesn't make sense as there are no coins

Incorrect.

In many business scenarios, USD financial amounts are calculated to the third or even the fourth decimal place to track a fraction of a penny.

Indeed, at the gasoline station you may think you are paying [USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar) $ 4.12 per gallon. Actually you are paying USD $ 4.129. They tack nearly an extra penny on to the price posted up on their big signs, using that third decimal place. Read the pump’s fine print to see the full truth.

---

Alternatively, you can represent money as an integer using a `long`. For [USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_dollar), multiply by 100 to get pennies into the integer. Or multiply by a thousand or ten-thousand for fractional penny.